# how to use firebase authentication (for google/facebook sign-in) in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

I know how to use the email password part of firebase. but I'm having a problem with finding any docs or code for the Login/Signup with google/facebook in jetpack compose.

Comment: You can check my [project](https://github.com/commandiron/BesonAppCleanArch) that I use firebase auth and google auth.

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) is how you can authenticate to Firebase using Google One Tap in Jetpack Compose.

Comment: thank you! I'm guessing there is no cases for facebook one?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out**

```
package com.example.signinwithgoogle

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.rememberLauncherForActivityResult
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Email
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.signinwithgoogle.ui.theme.SignInWithGoogleTheme
import com.firebase.ui.auth.R
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider

private const val TAG = "MainActivity"


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SignInWithGoogleTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    GoogleSignIn()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
@Composable
fun GoogleSignIn(){
    Log.d(TAG, "GoogleSignIn: called")

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    val result1 = remember {
        mutableStateOf<ActivityResult?>(null)
    }
    val startForResult =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            result1.value = result
        }


    Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        if (mAuth.currentUser != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FirstPage: going to second page")
            Toast.makeText(context, "Already signed in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        } else {
            val googleSignInClient = getGoogleLoginAuthI(
                context,
                stringResource(id = R.string.default_web_client_id)
            )

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    startForResult.launch(googleSignInClient.signInIntent)
                }
                ) {
                    Image(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Email,
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(48.dp)
                            .padding(4.dp),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSpacing))
                    Text(text = "Sign With Google")
                }

                if (result1.value != null) {
                    val result = result1.value
                    if (result != null) {
                        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            val intent = result.data
                            if (result.data != null) {
                                val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> =
                                    com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent)
                                handleGoogleSignInResult(task, context = context)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




fun handleGoogleSignInResult(task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>, context: Context): List<String> {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult: called")
    val user = task.result
    firebaseAuthWithGoogleI(task, context = context)

    return listOf(
        user.id.toString(),
        user.email.toString(),
        user.displayName.toString(),
        user.familyName.toString(),
        user.givenName.toString(),
        user.photoUrl.toString(),
        user.serverAuthCode.toString()
    )
}

fun firebaseAuthWithGoogleI(task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>, context: Context) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle: login with firebase")
    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(task.result.idToken, null)
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener { t ->
        if (t.isSuccessful) {
            showToastMsg(context = context, "Auth successful")
            Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle: Added to auth")

        } else {
            showToastMsg(context = context, "Auth failed")
            Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle: failed ${t.exception}")
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        showToastMsg(context = context, "Auth failed")
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle: failed ${it.message}")
    }
}


fun getGoogleLoginAuthI(context: Context, requestIdToken: String): GoogleSignInClient {
    Log.d(TAG, "getGoogleLoginAuth: called")

    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .requestIdToken(requestIdToken)
        .requestId()
        .requestProfile()
        .build()
    return com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso)
}

fun showToastMsg(context: Context, msg: String) {
    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).